# WChar_t set to null in C++

Tags: c++

I have a variable is in WCharArray form. I want to empty the array and to reuse it. How can I set this variable to null?

```
fileName[1024] = L'\0';
```

Is this the way to empty the array?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [help] and [ask] on how to ask a proper question.  You don't show any code, or what you have attempted.

Comment: C++ has a standard type called `wchar_t`. What is `WChar_t`? And what is `WCharArray`? You can't set an array to null. Does it contain a null-terminated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) to completely fill the array with zeros.

```
std::fill(fileName, fileName+1024, 0);
```

If you have C++11 it would be better to use [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) to get the iterators for the call.

```
std::fill(std::begin(fileName), std::end(fileName), 0);
```

To initialize it for the first time you can use an initializer. The default value for `wchar_t` is zero so there's no need to even give any values in the brackets.

```
wchar_t fileName[1024] = {};
```